# How do you get the 'use automatic reference counting' checkbox to show when starting a new mac application in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I just started learning about mac application development by doing this tutorial https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/GettingStarted.html

I feel dumb because I am stuck on the very first step. It says to make sure that the "use automatic reference counting" checkbox is checked, but I don't even have that checkbox.

This is a screenshot from the tutorial:
[image]

and this is a screenshot from my laptop while following along with the tutorial: 
[image]

Since I am not even yet sure what automatic reference counting is I feel stuck because I don't know if it is important or not. Does anyone know why this option is not shown in my xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick version: automatic reference counting is now the default, so just go to the next step.

The longer version: That tutorial appears to be written using Xcode 4.4 in the examples. The current version of Xcode is 5.1, and Apple has made a bunch of changes between then and now, some cosmetic and some more substantial.

One of those changes is that automatic reference counting (ARC) is now the default choice for new projects. ARC is a method of memory management where the compiler and runtime work together to keep track of which objects are still in use, and release the ones which aren't. When this technology was first introduced, it had some rough spots, and so it made sense to make it optional.

Apple is really pushing everyone to use ARC for all projects, so they removed the checkbox in the create project dialog. I'm not sure when this happened; may have been Xcode 5.0 or 5.1.

All that said: the tutorial you're using was written for an earlier version of Xcode than you're using. The big concepts are all going to still apply, but you'll run into issues from time to time where the screenshots don't look the same or the options are slightly different. So take a deep breath and just go for it. :)

Comment: Awesome, appreciate it. Just wasn't sure if I had forgot to install some sort of package or something.

Comment: Nope! Just Apple being "helpful".